# Fortran - nf90_open - SIGSEGV

Tags: fortran, netcdf

I am using an old fortran program given to me to open a netcdf file, read its contents, perform some calculations and interpolation, and write the data to another file format. I have very little experience in fortran, so please any help would be deeply appreciated.

The program is compiled successfully:

```
ifort -c -CB -CU -ftrapuv -par_report0 -vec_report0 -heap-arrays -O0 -stand f90 -check all -traceback -fstack-protector -assume protect_parens -implicitnone -debug -gen-interfaces -check arg_temp_created -ftrapuv -g -convert big_endian -I/opt/cray/netcdf/4.3.0/INTEL/130/include/ CAM_netcdf_to_WRF_intermediate.f90 ; ifort CAM_netcdf_to_WRF_intermediate.o -L/opt/cray/netcdf/4.3.0/INTEL/130/lib -lnetcdf -lnetcdff
```

The program crashes, running out of bounds while trying to read in the netcdf file:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7657d33 in nf_open_ (A1=0x18 <Address 0x18 out of bounds>, A2=0x4e04bc <__NLITPACK_19>,
    A3=0x7fffffff90ec, C1=128) at fort-control.c:27
27      fort-control.c: No such file or directory.
```

Running GDB, using 'bt full':

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7657d33 in nf_open_ (A1=0x18 <Address 0x18 out of bounds>, A2=0x4e04bc <__NLITPACK_19>,
    A3=0x7fffffff90ec, C1=128) at fort-control.c:27
27      fort-control.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt full
#0  0x00007ffff7657d33 in nf_open_ (A1=0x18 <Address 0x18 out of bounds>,
    A2=0x4e04bc <__NLITPACK_19>, A3=0x7fffffff90ec, C1=128) at fort-control.c:27
        B1 = 0x0
        B3 = 5113020
#1  0x00007ffff76630ac in NETCDF::nf90_open (
    path=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x18>, mode=0, ncid=-858993460,
    chunksize=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>,
    cache_size=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>,
    cache_nelems=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>,
    cache_preemption=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>,
    comm=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>,
    info=<error reading variable: Cannot access memory at address 0x0>, .tmp.PATH.len_V$ffc=128)
    at netcdf4_file.f90:64
        nf90_open = -144388088
        ret = 0
        preemption_out = 0
        nelems_out = -1
        size_out = 0
        preemption_in = 32767
        nelems_in = -134664192
        size_in = 32767
```

The program is below:

```
program CAM_netcdf_to_WRF_intermediate
  use netcdf
  implicit none

  ! Declarations:
  integer, parameter :: outfile_diagnostics = 16
  integer, parameter :: infile_CAM_files_and_dates = 15
  character(len=24) :: HDATE

  ! dimensions:
  integer, parameter :: nx_CAM=288,ny_CAM=192,nz_CAM=26 &
       ,nfields=5,nfields2d=9,nfields2d_to_read=5 &
       ,nz_soil=4,nz_CLM=1,nfields_soil=2
  integer, parameter :: nz_WRF=38
  character(len=128) :: netcdf_cam_filename,netcdf_clm_filename,netcdf_pop_filename
  character(len=128) :: netcdf_ice_filename
  integer :: iEOF
  logical :: EOF

  ! open outpuf log file:
  open(outfile_diagnostics,form='formatted',file="Output/CCSM2WRF.log")

  ! read the first date and netcdf file name from the input file:
  open(infile_CAM_files_and_dates,form='formatted',file="Input/CCSM2WRF.input")
  read(infile_CAM_files_and_dates,*,iostat=iEOF) netcdf_cam_filename,netcdf_clm_filename,&
                        netcdf_pop_filename,netcdf_ice_filename,hdate
  if (iEOF<0) then;
print *, "EOF True"
     EOF=.true.;
  else;
print *, "EOF False"
     EOF=.false.;
  end if

     call dummy_read(nz_WRF,hdate,outfile_diagnostics,netcdf_cam_filename &
                    ,netcdf_clm_filename,netcdf_pop_filename &
                    ,netcdf_ice_filename,nx_CAM,ny_CAM,nz_CAM)
  stop
end program CAM_netcdf_to_WRF_intermediate

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
SUBROUTINE HANDLE_ERR(STATUS)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  use netcdf
  implicit none
  INTEGER STATUS
  IF (STATUS .NE. NF90_NOERR) THEN
     PRINT *, NF90_STRERROR(STATUS)
     STOP 'Stopped'
  ENDIF
END SUBROUTINE HANDLE_ERR

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Subroutine dummy_read &
     (nz_WRF,outfile_diagnostics,netcdf_cam_filename &
     ,netcdf_clm_filename,netcdf_pop_filename,netcdf_ice_filename &
     ,nx_CAM,ny_CAM,nz_CAM)
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  use netcdf
  implicit none
  integer :: nz_WRF
  integer :: nx_CAM,ny_CAM,nz_CAM
  character(len=128) :: filename
  character(len=24) :: HDATE
  integer :: outfile_diagnostics
  integer :: STATUS, NCID, NCID_clm, NCID_pop, NCID_ice
  character(len=128) :: netcdf_cam_filename, netcdf_clm_filename, netcdf_pop_filename
  character(len=128) :: netcdf_ice_filename

  ! open output files for metgrid in WRF/WPS intermediate format:
  write(filename,'("Output/FILE:",A13)') hdate(1:13)
  write(outfile_diagnostics,*) "output intermediate file filename=",filename
  open(10,form='unformatted',file=filename)

  write(filename,'("Output/SST:",A13)') hdate(1:13)
  write(outfile_diagnostics,*) "output intermediate SST file filename=",filename
  open(11,form='unformatted',file=filename)

  STATUS = NF90_OPEN(netcdf_cam_filename, 0, NCID)
!  STATUS = NF90_OPEN(path = "Inputdata/ind/cam_CCSM4_historical_197909-197912-1979090100.nc", mode= 0, ncid = NCID)
  IF (STATUS .NE. NF90_NOERR) CALL HANDLE_ERR(STATUS)
print *, "first status conditional statement"
  STATUS = NF90_OPEN(netcdf_clm_filename, 0, NCID_clm)
  IF (STATUS .NE. NF90_NOERR) CALL HANDLE_ERR(STATUS)
  STATUS = NF90_OPEN(netcdf_pop_filename, 0, NCID_pop)
  IF (STATUS .NE. NF90_NOERR) CALL HANDLE_ERR(STATUS)
  STATUS = NF90_OPEN(netcdf_ice_filename, 0, NCID_ice)
  IF (STATUS .NE. NF90_NOERR) CALL HANDLE_ERR(STATUS)
  status=NF90_CLOSE(NCID)
  status=NF90_CLOSE(NCID_clm)
  status=NF90_CLOSE(NCID_pop)
  status=NF90_CLOSE(NCID_ice)

print *, "Leaving dummy, going to MAIN"
  return
end Subroutine dummy_read
```

The open statement works if I hard-code the path of the netcdf file (see the commented out line within the dummy_read subroutine). Printing out the netcdf_cam_filename within main returns a valid string, however printing out the string within the dummy_read subroutine returns an empty string. I am uncertain why the netcdf_cam_filename string is not making it into the subroutine correctly.

Please ask if you need additional information. I only posted pieces of the code that I think applies to the error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `-g -traceback` to get more useful backtrace.

Comment: The use of -g -traceback does not give additional information.

Comment: Mark- I am not sure what you mean -the fortran function 'nf90_open' is not in the code, but is loaded with this statement ('use netcdf').

Comment: Is the argument mismatch between the call and definition of `dummy_read` a typo from your example, or does it exist in your actual code as well?

Comment: @casey - the problem exists when trying to open the file inside the subroutine.
`STATUS = NF90_OPEN(netcdf_cam_filename, 0, NCID)
IF (STATUS .NE. NF90_NOERR) CALL HANDLE_ERR(STATUS)`
The STATUS is returned as an error, calling the HANDLE_ERR subroutine where the program is stopped. The subroutine appears to forget the string attached to netcdf_cam_filename.

Comment: @user2030765 yes, but in your example you are calling the subroutine improperly and this can cause many problems. Your actual and dummy arguments are mismatched and differ in number in your example. This can be your problem but i want to verify it isnt merely a typo in your post.

Comment: The code is copied from the fortran file, so there should not be any typos. I do not see any mismatch (in the fortran file or above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your subroutine call is mismatched to the actual definition.

Your call to `dummy_read` is:

```
call dummy_read(nz_WRF,hdate,outfile_diagnostics,netcdf_cam_filename &
                ,netcdf_clm_filename,netcdf_pop_filename &
                ,netcdf_ice_filename,nx_CAM,ny_CAM,nz_CAM)
```

While your declaration of `dummy_read` is:

```
Subroutine dummy_read &
 (nz_WRF,outfile_diagnostics,netcdf_cam_filename &
 ,netcdf_clm_filename,netcdf_pop_filename,netcdf_ice_filename &
 ,nx_CAM,ny_CAM,nz_CAM)
```

Or shown a different way:

```
call       dummy_read(nz_WRF,hdate,              outfile_diagnostics,netcdf_cam_filename,netcdf_clm_filename,netcdf_pop_filename,netcdf_ice_filename,nx_CAM,ny_CAM,nz_CAM)
Subroutine dummy_read(nz_WRF,outfile_diagnostics,netcdf_cam_filename,netcdf_clm_filename,netcdf_pop_filename,netcdf_ice_filename,nx_CAM,             ny_CAM,nz_CAM)
```

Which results in an argument mismatch.  The dummy argument `outfile_diagnostics` is associated with the actual argument `hdate` and so on.  You are passing 10 arguments to a subroutine declared to take 9.

---

You might wonder why the compiler produced an executable in such a case rather than producing an error.  This is because you are calling the procedure with an implicit interface and Fortran trusts you to do the right thing.  Fortran can detect argument mismatches but to do so you need to provide an explicit interface.  Aside from explicitly declaring the interface, the easiest ways to do this are to either make the procedure a module procedure (by putting the subroutine into a module) or an internal procedure (by putting the procedure in the main program after a `contains` statement).

You can also ask the compiler to provide high levels of warnings to avoid this problem.  Compiling with gfortran with `-Wall` produces this warning with your code:

```
     call dummy_read(nz_WRF,hdate,outfile_diagnostics,netcdf_cam_filename &
                            1
Warning: Type mismatch in argument 'outfile_diagnostics' at (1); passed CHARACTER(1) to INTEGER(4)
```

Adiitionally, ifort provides the option `-gen-interfaces` flag that will automatically generate modules to contain external procedures.  I would however consider this a tool to help port code to newer language standards than something to rely on.

Comment: @casey- Thank you. This appears to have fixed the issue.

Comment: +1 I would add that this would not happen if the subroutine was placed in a module or was an internal procedure of inside the program.